I cannot boot the EFI in VirtualBox
I cannot boot the EFI in VirtualBox.
I did everything according to this video, I have macOS, I installed VB and now I am trying to run Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.1 LTS, when I have written the name of file, it is shows - unsupported.
I do not know what to do, command  edit startup.nsh prints:

"access denied"



Do you have a 64-bit version selected under Settings>General?

Are you running this on an Intel Mac or ARM (Apple Silicon) Mac?

@DavidAnderson, Yes

@grawity, I have ARM

As VirtualBox relies on hardware virtualization done by your CPU, it only supports running software built for the same architecture as the host CPU.
The files you're trying to run are for Intel/AMD CPUs (x86_64 aka amd64) as the x64 in their names implies, but you say you have an Apple Silicon (ARM64) system, which is a different CPU architecture and cannot run x86_64 code.
You need to re-download Ubuntu for "arm64" – not "amd64".
(macOS itself can run Intel apps through Rosetta emulation, but this only works within the OS – it doesn't extend to full virtualization software.)

There is only problem: interenet gives me links only about ubuntu server, not desktop

Sure, but Ubuntu Server arm64 is still more correct than Ubuntu Desktop amd64 when it comes to your CPU. It's more-or-less the same Ubuntu anyway – you can still install a graphical interface and all the usual packages on Ubuntu Server (I think they even have whole metapackages that just transform one edition into another). It seems there are semi-official Desktop images though: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042696/
